# Replace tokens in context file

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, ant, war

I'm assembling war file using ant script. I have `context.xml` file with resource definitions, which I need to place inside META-INF folder. But some resource properties are defined only at build time, that's why these properties are defined as tokens, which I need to replace with values when building and copying context.xml to META-INF.

This is how copy the file:

```
<war>
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/server/resource/context.xml"/>
        <globmapper from="*" to="META-INF/*"/>
    </mappedresources>
</war>
```

I could replace properties with `<replace>` task, but I want to keep original file not changed. How can I replace the tokens during war assembling? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing custom ant task

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest approach will be to copy the `context.xml` original into a staging directory (ideally a child of your build output directory so it gets deleted on a clean), then perform the `<replace>` and `<war>`.